# disable ARC For Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, linker-errors

I am using this framework in my app. i want to disable ARC For this Framework. it is having only .h files. Any solution

[IOTCamera](https://github.com/Shalow/CameraMonitor_iOS)

it is showing this Error

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Camera", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PVPetLiveShowController.o
 (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CameraShowGLView, _OBJC_CLASS_$_Cameras )
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

Comment: Your IOTCamera framework compiled 2 years ago for only 32 bit. So its giving error for 64 bit. Get latest 64-bit supported framework..its not ARC issue.

Comment: Guru, I am unable to find 64 bit IOTCamera Framework,Can you Please Provide me any Link

Answer (score 1):

Your framework is already compiled. This is not related to ARC. Your framework is not compiled for arm64.

- If you are using Xcode check this settings when you compile your framework 
  [image]
- check that "**Build Active Architecture Only**" is set to **NO** (not as shown in screenshot)
- recompile framework

Comment: @VarinderSingh, you need to do this for framework before compiling it. You can't do anything with compiled framework.

Comment: Please give me a little explation.I didn't get u @Guru